# sphinx doc with different latex versions

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

Recently, I found some issue with different version of tex. In our company, some are using texlive2018 and some are using texlive2017. In our `conf.py`, I put

```
latex_elements = {
    'preamble': '''\usepackage{chngcntr}
                 \counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
                 \counterwithin{table}{chapter}''',
}
```

It runs OK in texlive2017 but have a `redefined error` in texlive2018. If I remove `\usepackage{chngcntr}`, then texlive2018 works, but texlive2017 have a `undefined error`. Certainly, it is triggered by some changes in newer version of texlive. But I am wondering if there is a way so that it works on both texlive version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the macros of `chngcntr` have been moved to the LaTeX format with TeXLive2018.

A new version of `chngcntr` package starts with this

```
% version 1.1 this package has been adoped into the format so does not 
% need to do anything in current latex releases.

\@ifundefined{counterwithout}{}{%
\PackageInfo{chngcntr}{\string\counterwithout\space already defined.\MessageBreak
Quitting chngcntr}%
\endinput
}
```

Thus all should be find if your TeXLive2018 has the v1.1a 2018/04/09 version of the `chngctr` package. Please check. Is this the Info you see? this is not an Error.

Else you can always do (beware the `r` else double the backslashes)

```
latex_elements = {
    'preamble': r'''\ifdefined\counterwithout\else\usepackage{chngcntr}\fi
                 \counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
                 \counterwithin{table}{chapter}''',
}
```

By the way there was a related [issue](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/38) with the LaTeX format, but it has been fixed since.